# Use Scala to create a list with the squares from 0 to count – 1 as lists with duplicates

Tags: list, scala

I want to use **fill** and **tabulate** to create a list with the squares from 0 to count -1 as lists with duplicates.

Something like this:

```
squareNtimes(5)

//> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), List(4, 4, 4, 4, 4), List(9, 9, 9, 9, 9), List(16, 16, 16, 16, 16))
```

I wrote this function:

```
def squareNtimes(count: Int) = List.fill(count)(List.tabulate(count)(n => n * n))
```

But the output is not the same:

```
//> res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16), List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16), List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16), List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16), List(0, 1, 4, 9, 16))
```

Does anyone know what is the mistake that I am making?

Comment: Do you have to use those 2 functions?

Comment: Yes, I have to use fill and tabulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, I think this should work:

```
List.tabulate(count)(n => List.fill(count)(n * n))
```

Comment: @user2699664: Sure thing!